# Unit testing Angular 2 Service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Im new to whole unit testing scene with Angular, so would be great if guys could point me in the direction.. Im trying to create a fake service and pass back data to which i can run a few simple test..

When I go to run the test it seems to fail with

Server error
  at webpack:///~/rxjs/Subscriber.js:194:0 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:20301

I don't think it my webpack config.. Here is my code anway...

```
import { SearchModule } from './search.module';
import { SearchService } from './search.services';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http'; 
import { inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';  
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

class SearchServiceMock {

search() {

    return Observable.of(
        [
            {
            "title": "title_1",
            "artist": "artist_1",
            "release": "06/02/2016",
            "slug": "slug-1"
        },
        {
            "title": "title_2",
            "artist": "artist_1",
            "release": " 27/01/2017",
            "slug": "slug-2"
        },
        {
            "title": "title_3",
            "artist": "artist_3",
            "release": "17/02/2017",
            "slug": "slug-3"
        }
        ]
    )

}

}

describe('Service: TracksServices', () => {

let searchService: SearchService;

beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ SearchModule, HttpModule ],
        providers: [
        { provide: SearchService, useClass: SearchServiceMock },
    ]
}));

beforeEach(inject([SearchService], (s: any) => {
    searchService = s;
}));

it('Search results 3', () => {

    searchService.search('track 1', 1, 4).subscribe(
        (x:any) => {     

            // expect(x).toContain(track);
            expect(x.length).toEqual(3);

        }
    );

});

});
```

The test still seems to be getting the real service i think when I want to use a fake one

Comment: Why do you want to use a fake service when you're *trying to test that service?!* You should ideally be writing tests that don't still pass when you delete the thing they're supposed to exercise.

Answer (score 4):

## Purpose of Test Doubles

I know the pain of getting into Unit testing, in JavaScript, and in Angular, and it took me a few tries to wrap my head around it.

**So I hope the following explanation will help sort out the confusion:**

The object you are testing is called *"Object under test"*

In your case it is the `SearchService`.

A *Mock* is one type of fake objects.

These fake objects have lots of various names and purposes - Mocks, Spies, stubs, etc..

But the general name coined by Gerard Meszaros and explained [here](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html) is **Test Doubles**.

The *object under test* often has dependencies on other objects.
These dependencies are also called **collaborators**

Replacing your object's *collaborators* with *test doubles* is done for the purpose of testing how the Object interacts with them.

The idea is to "record" that interaction, and it is done with spies (in Jasmine - `jasmine.createSpy()`).

## Unit Testing Angular 2 Services

**One way of testing http calls -**

You're not obligated to use `TestBed` for testing a service, it is more useful for testing reusable components, because of its DOM capabilites.

You can create a fake object which has the same methods like Angular's Http objects, but replaced with spies.

Then create a `new SearchService(httpSpy)` instance. 
This will give you a copy of your service, which you can test.

Then call methods on that the **REAL** service under test and investigate the relevant spy for the result.

**Another way to test http calls**
You can use the `MockBackend` class and configure the Http service to use a fake backend instead, like [in this doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html)

## About the error you are getting

It's hard to say without seeing a plunker of the example with the real service under test code.

## More Theory Material (in video)

If you're new to testing, you can learn more about *Test Doubles* and how unit testing is done in my (free) theory course about [JavaScript Unit Testing and TDD](https://www.hirez.io/c/javascript-unit-testing-and-tdd-theory/e/episode-1-what-are-unit-tests)

Hope it helps.